# Getting error of not staying within study area using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0

Why is ArcMap giving this error of not staying within the study area?

I tried to change the coordinates and the datum and still an error occurs, follow the prints below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: What's the issue? Is it the error with the define projection tool? Or the other thing you are saying about the not staying part? If it's the tool, I heavily suspect that the layer is already assisted with a projection, and to alter that, use the project tool instead. Clarify further if you face issues.